# What does that output of Sum mean?

Tags: summation

I made the computation

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
r = Sum[1/2^(k*n/(k + n)), {k, 1, 2*n}, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0]
```

and got

> ```
> (1-4^(-(n^2/(n+Sum`SumqBaseDump`u$274844))))/(-1+2^(n/(n+Sum`SumqBaseDump`u$274844)))
> ```

I can find nothing about `SumqBaseDump` in the Mathematica documentation.

Addition. It should be noticed `DiscreteLimit` works with `r`:

```
DiscreteLimit[r, n -> Infinity]
```

> 1

Comment: @Kuba: Thank you for your edit.

Comment: Looks like  a bug in `Sum` to me.

Comment: Same behavior in _v8.0.4_ and _v9.0.1_. `Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0` isn't necessary to produce the result.

Comment: @Mariyusz Iwaniuk: And no constructive result.

Comment: Same with `RSolve[{a[m + 1] == a[m] + (1/2)^(n m /(n + m)), a[1] == 1/Sqrt[2]}, 
 a[m], m]`.

Comment: I think it is quite obvious that this is a bug. Did you already report it to Wolfram Support?

Comment: remark that `Sum[1/2^(1/(1/n + 1/k)), {k, 1, 2*n}]` avoids this specific bug.

Comment: In 13.1 returns unevaluated. DiscreteLimit also fails, does not print 1. Workaround above also fails @Wouter. RSolve and DiscreteLimit after does work though, 1+1/Sqrt[2] -2^(1-m).